# Yeoman - How to store global configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

So I've created a Yeoman generator, and I want to add some prompts for some global config.

I'd like it so the first time you run the generator to ask for a github username and token, then store it somehow so you don't need to enter it next time you run the generator.

I've tried using `this.config` but I think that creates a `yo-rc` file in the generated project.

Is there anyway I can save some global config? If so, how can I do it? Can't seem to find anything about it online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `store` property on the prompt to store and remember the answers.

See [Remembering user preferences](http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to save the config and only prompt if it isn't present?
I don't want the prompt to keep coming up if they have already entered the details.

Comment: @SimonSturgess no it's not possible because if that was the case, it'd be impossible for the user to ever change their mind. This would result in poor user experience. That's why we don't do it this way, and I believe you should not try to hack around it.

Comment: I've done it the way you suggested, but I think there should be a way to do it and just have an option you pass when you run the generator which lets you reset your config if you want to change.

I want to let users enter their github username and api key, stuff they are likely never to change. Doing it this way means every time they run the generator there are two prompts which basically don't need to be there.